# How to use the Lit-Element query decorator?

Tags: lit-element

Code fails Typescript compilation when attempting to use the Lit-Element query decorator.

With tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "outDir": "../../out/client",
    "allowJs": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  }
}
```

and package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "lit-element": "^2.2.1"
  },
```

tsc command yields the following error:

> > > Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression.
> > >           Type '{ kind: string; placement: string; key: any; descriptor: any; }' is not assignable to type 'void'.

However, if I comment out the two lines of the decorator, and un-comment the equivalent get function, no errors.

```js
    @customElement("my-app")
    export default class extends LitElement {
      @query("p")
      p: any;

      // get p() {
      //   return this.shadowRoot.querySelector("p");
      // }

      render() {
        return html`
          Hello World!
          <p>A paragraph</p>
        `;
      }
```

I expected identical behavior using either the query decorated property or the property getter.

Comment: Tried to reproduce, and I get no error on VSCode :(

Comment: Thanks @LostInBrittany Are you using a preprocessor/Babel? I've updated the question with my config, using tsc without Babel. Fails in both lint and compilation for me.

Comment: No pre-processor, using directly the TS in VScode. Using also a very simple tsconfig.json: {
    "compilerOptions": {
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "module": "es6",
        "target": "es6",
        "experimentalDecorators": true 
    }
}

Comment: Does it resolve if setting `"useDefineForClassFields": false`, per [lit.dev docs](https://lit.dev/docs/tools/publishing/#compiling-with-typescript)?

Answer (score 2):

Do you correctly import the `query` annotation?

The following element works for me:

```js
/**
 * Import LitElement base class, html helper function,
 * and TypeScript decorators
 **/
import {
    LitElement, html, customElement, query
  } from 'lit-element';

  @customElement("my-app")
  export default class extends LitElement {
    @query("p")
    p: any;

    // get p() {
    //   return this.shadowRoot.querySelector("p");
    // }

    render() {
      return html`
        Hello World!
        <p>A paragraph</p>
      `;
    }
}
```

With a `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "module": "es6",
        "target": "es6",
        "experimentalDecorators": true 
    }
}
```